# Remove noise in a graph

Tags: graph, graph-theory

Let `G=(V,E)` be a DAG. `V` is the set of vertices in the graph, while `E` is the set of edges connecting the vertices in `V`.

Assume that noise is introduced in the graph, i.e., some non-existing edges are inserted in `E`. In this way:

- roots may be "hidden" in the graph, becoming internal nodes
- leaves may become internal nodes too
- cycles are inserted in the graph

I am looking for an algorithm that removes cycles while still preserving the topology of the initial DAG. I am using DFS for now: when I encounter a loop, one of the edges composing the loop is deleted. However, this does not assure that roots and leaves are recovered. Can I found something useful in the state of the art?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i'm afraid there is not enough information available to achieve your goal: imagine a degenerate tree consisting of a single path `v1...vn` only. after insertion of a spurious edge `(vn, v1)` into your graph, the graph topology does not provide any hint on which edge to delete in order to restore the original. in particular you will not be able to reconstruct the former root and leaf.